# Why will my iPhone 5 not connect to the Internet through 4g but will on wifi

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5 will not connect to the Internet via mobile data but will on wifi ? I have rebooted it several times, the first time worked but a few weeks later it has happened again and now won't clear. Help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Settings app, then Cellular. Make sure that Cellular Data is on, then go to Cellular Data Options and make sure that all settings (except Data Roaming) are enabled.